# Compound interest ($r$ in terms of $\frac{dA}{dt}$)

Tags: financial-economics

Suppose the amount of money in bank account that is compounded annually is given by $A(t)$. The annual rate of interest is $r$. Find a relation between $\displaystyle\frac{dA}{dt}$ and $r$.

**My attempt:**

$A(t)=A(0)(1+r)^t$

$\displaystyle\frac{dA}{dt}=A(0)(1+r)^t\ln (1+r)$

Dividing, we get

$\displaystyle\frac{1}{A}\frac{dA}{dt}=\ln(1+r)$

However, I think the answer should be $\displaystyle r=\frac{1}{A}\frac{dA}{dt}$.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong. Since
$$
\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{\ln(1+r)}{r} = 1
$$
(to see why: use [l'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) or Taylor approximation) holds, for small numbers $r$ 
$$
\ln(1+r) \approx r.
$$